Pull photos from Pixel 6a recovery mode, or fix bootloop problem
My wife's Pixel 6a battery died during use and when I charged it and restarted it, it is stuck in a bootloop.  I have the option for a factory reset which I assume will work, but I have photos that aren't backed up that I'd really like to get off of it.
Safe mode doesn't seem to work, unless I'm doing it wrong.
I can get into the bootloader and it connects to my Windows PC, but it says there are no drivers for the Pixel in the device manager.
I can also get into recovery mode.  I am not very familiar with recovery mode, and not all options are working. Here's a summary of options:

Reboot to system now

Reboot to bootloader

Enter fastboot

Apply update from ADB (I have read a little about this but haven't tried anything.  It seems to work and the phone shows up as a universal serial bus device in the device manager.  I've got my main hope in a tutorial here)

Apply update from SD card (the phone doesn't have an SD slot, it says installation aborted)

Wipe data/factory reset (trying to avoid it until pictures are recovered)

Mount system (doesn't work and gives and error)
ERROR:   recovery: [libfs_mgr] Unable to enable ext4 verity on /dev/block/platform/14700000.ufs/by-name/metadata because /system/bin/tune2fs is missing
Mounted /system.
ERROR:   recovery: [libfs+mgr] Unknown volume for path [/sdcard]
ERROR:   recovery: -- Couldn't mount /sdcard.


View recovery logs (seems to work.  Gives 29232 bytes of logs)

Run graphics test (doesn't work.  It says installing system update, then error, then installing system update again, then it aborts the update)

Run locale test (seems to work)

Power off


If anyone has any ideas or can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks.

Be aware that there is at the moment a bug known which can brick  a Pixel 6a if you perform a factory reset. Therefore whatever you do, I would recommend not to perform a factory reset at the moment. For more details see https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/281577056 The tune2fs error message may indicate that your device already is affected by this problem. So I would recommend contacting Google.

Thank you robert.  I didn't know about this.

I checked into that and it seems almost like it's the exact same issue.  I'll be watching it closely.  Thank you so much for pointing that out.

While the tune2fs error message is the same, the rest of the message looks different, so I hope it's a different issue and fixable (I assume the phone hasn't been factory reset recently?)

I am assuming you didn't do a factory reset (you need the photos). For me your third para is most important. What does the device manager of windows say? If it says it's a USB device, then extremely sorry, it's R.I.P // I have read of at least three such cases in this XDA thread

To clarify, when I say "such cases", I am talking of your device is shown as USB in device manager, not what caused it

bootloader is unlocked?

I haven't' done a factory reset.  The device manager says it's a usb device, but that is when the phone is on the boot loader.  Does that mean it's bricked?  I am also following the google support page for this issue (or at least a very similar issue).  It's got almost 1500 people who report the same problem, but no updates in a week.   Here's the link:  https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/283220215?hl=en

I guess this issue is closed.  I wasn't ever able to find a way to get the pictures (however my wife had backed them up online, so that was good).  I was monitoring the google support page.  It got up to over 2000 people who had a BLOD after updating.  They finally updated and said there was a solution and you needed to call or chat with support.  After a 30 minute chat they notified me that my only option was to mail in the device for repair, that I would pay for.  I figured at this point I might as well do a factory reset, which solved all issues, except for loss of anything not backed up.
